# Flutter AlertDialog Navigator.pop(context) returning a black screen

Tags: flutter

i'm using NetworkGiffyDialog for custom alertdialog But it gives blackscreen background and sometimes apps crash
 prob here :

```
onOkButtonPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

function that i call :

```
void showAlert(BuildContext context, String txt, String logo) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => NetworkGiffyDialog(
                image: Image.asset("Assets/" + logo + ".gif"),
                title: Text('Produit Radar',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                description: Text(
                  txt,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                onOkButtonPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `context` you are using with this code - `Navigator.of(context)` - is the one you are passing to your `showAlert` function, which is probably the context of the route on top of which you are displaying the dialog. Because of this, when you call `pop()` you are actually popping the route, instead of the dialog. If that is the first route in the navigation stack, the result will be the black screen you mention.

Replace `builder: (_)` with `builder: (BuildContext context)` so that when you call `Navigator.of(context).pop();` you are actually using the dialog's context and as such the dialog will be dismissed.

Comment: problem that i call multiple time thaat fct , if user click ok no prob for me dialog will close , but when no action  is done and after diplau=ying rslt in that dialog ( example 3 dialog showed ) user need to press ok multiple time to close all dialog

Answer (score 0):

Set the useRootNavigator attribute of the showAlert class to false.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).